# how to count JSON loop to read xx more results

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have the following JSON loop which cuts off at 10 records.  However, if for instance I have 20 records, I would like my append to say '+ 10 more...'.

How could I accomplish this?

```
$.each(data, function(i, value){
    if(i == 10){ 
           var book_title = value.book_title;
           $('.notice').append('<div>+ XX more...</div>');
           return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the need for tagging it to PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Modulus operator:

```
if(i > 0 && i % 10 == 0){ 
       var book_title = value.book_title;
       $('.notice').append('<div>+ XX more...</div>');
       return false;
 }
```

Comment: I can see where you are going with this, and thank you.  However I'm unsure this fits the purpose and this may be due to my poor example.  

If I have a scenario whereby I have 55 items in my loop, I need the append to say '45 more...'

Comment: That definitely provides a solution for me.  Thank you so much